How is RegisterStartupScript called when Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered?
I'm following MSDN on RegisterStartupScript, but it has me confused.
  public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
    String csname1 = "PopupScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
        
    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
    {
        StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
        cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript> alert('Hello World!') </");
        cstext1.Append("script>");

        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
    }
  }

I want to call a function whenever a row on a GridView is clicked, so I might do it many times.
protected void gridview_RowClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); 
  sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>function ChangeColor() {"); 
  sb.Append("var lbl = document.getElementById('lblDisplayDate');"); 
  sb.Append("lbl.style.color='green';"); 
  sb.Append("}</script>"); 

  //Render the function definition. 
  if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("JSScriptBlock")) 
  {
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSScriptBlock", sb.ToString()); 
  }

  //Render the function invocation. 
  string funcCall = "<script language='javascript'>ChangeColor();</script>"; 

  if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript"))
  { 
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript", funcCall); 
  } 
}

The way I understand it, if .IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScriptBlock") is false, the next line registers it with the javascript to execute.
If another row in my grid is clicked, won't .IsStartupScriptRegistered=true so that RegisterStartupScript never executes?

See my post below for how script injection works. I would use ScriptManager, and not clientscript object. If you are using a UpdatePanel, then you need (must( to use ScriptManager. If you not using any update panels, then client script can be used, but I tend for the most part to just use ScriptManager. But, the short answer to above is no, since on each post-back, the injected script is cleared out. Also, always use register startup script, since it will be placed after the bootstrap classes and code has finished running

With each post-back (round trip to the server), then all such scripts (registered) as startup will not exist anymore.
Remember, a simple modification of a text box, or injection of a script occurs while the page is up on the server (during the short round trip of the page life cycle).
Hence, a simple change to a text box, or registering a script simply becomes part of the things you changed in the web page with code behind. Once all code behind is 100% complete, then the WHOLE page is sent back to the client side (with your changes to say some controls, and the script you injected to the page also travels down to the client side). The page is then displayed, rendering is completed, and then the JavaScript engine is loaded, and JavaScript code starts to run, including your injected script payload. On the server side, the page class and code behind is 100% disposed of, and removed from memory.
Since on next post back, such script does not have "view state", then such script injected will be lost and not exist.
This example markup shows this in action:
        <asp:Button ID="cmdScript" runat="server" Text="Register Script Test"
            OnClick="cmdScript_Click"                
            />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />


        <asp:Button ID="cmdPostBack" runat="server" Text="Buttion click test"
            OnClick="cmdPostBack_Click"
            />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="MyMessageArea" runat="server" Text="">
        </asp:Label>

And code behind:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void cmdScript_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyJava = "alert('hello world');";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "my code block",MyJava, true);

    }

    protected void cmdPostBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MyMessageArea.Text = "Server side button click";

        if (ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(this.GetType(), "my code block"))
            MyMessageArea.Text += " Script is registered";
        else
            MyMessageArea.Text += " Script is not registered";

    }

So, if we click the first button (script injection into the page), then the page travels back to the client, page rendering starts, and then the injected script runs.
However, if we then click the second button, note how it shows the script injection no longer exists. So, in summary, injected script does not persist, and thus no real need to test + check if you injected a startup script, as they don't persist from one page post back to the next.
Hence, we see this:

So, note closely how it don't matter if I click the second button before, or after the script injection, you can well see it is gone.
As noted, as another test page, try this code for the first button:
    protected void cmdScript_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyJava = "alert('hello world');";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "my code block",MyJava, true);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }

So, what will occur?
Well, the script will be injected into part of the page (that you can ONLY modify with code behind during that short round trip). So, the browser will "wait" and spin for 3 seconds. Once, and ONLY once the code behind is done, then the whole page is sent back to the client side, displays, and our injected script will run.
Hence we see this:

Note VERY closely - if the server side code is delayed for 3 seconds, then we see the browser "wait" spinner. You will not see the script run until such time that 100% of the code behind is 100% complete, and then (and only then) does the whole page with changes to controls, and including the injected script reach the client side, of which then controls and the script will run. In other words injected script does not run when you inject the script, but ONLY runs once the whole page completes the round trip back from the server to the client side.
Hence, you are free to inject script over and over on a post-back, and you can even use the same "key name", since as noted, on the next post-back, the injected script is lost each time on post-backs.

Thank you. That is a great answer. I wished Microsoft could add some explanations to their Help Files like this to help developers understand their tools better.

Sadly, I can't get this to fire the Main page from my Page 3 dialog. I'm beginning to think that it isn't possible. Nothing works.

How script injection works, and that of attempting to say reference other page classes of which I have pointed out go out of scope rather fast (page code classes can't as a general rule be referenced by other pages due to page lifecycle. You made some bad design choices here that will not work. Perhaps you should identify why the site will not work with newer browsers, since as noted, window.open can be used in newer browsers if it is a result of a user click. So, I would be 100% sure as to what and why the site only works with older browsers, as that may point to a far more simple solution
